# Button click event is not fired on first click when place inside popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, window, wpf-controls

I have placed a calendar control and a button control inside a popup control.

The problem I am facing:

1. Popup control is opened by an toggle button click.
2. After opening the popup control, I tried to select the date in the calendar on mouse click, now the calendar receives focus.
3. Now I'm trying to click the button in the popup, but the button click event fires only on the second click.

The problem is that on the first click the popup receives focus and only on the second click the event triggers.

Code

```xml
<Popup
    x:Name="Popup"
    Grid.Row="1"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Focusable="True"
    IsOpen="False"
    Placement="Bottom"
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Border}"
    StaysOpen="False">
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Calendar></Calendar>
            <Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Comment: @mm8 My question is i need to handle some function on button click after date selection in calendar, but it succeed only on second click on button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the `SelectedDatesChanged` event for the `Calendar` and call `Mouse.Capture(null)`:

```
private void Calendar_SelectedDatesChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

Comment: My main problem was that the control was show using a Mouse_Down (instead of click). So I had to click again to get the mouse in up state. If you use a Mouse_Up instead, it will work.